# get's ArgumentException only when doing async call to database in c# using linq QueryableExpression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following QueryableExpression

**Expression**:

```
public static IQueryable<IView> View(IQueryable<IView> dbSet)
{
    var result = dbSet
        .Include(vw => vw.Site);

    return result;
}
```

I invoke it like this and it works:

```
var demo = SitesExpressions.View(_db.GetWorker<View>().DbSet).Single(v => v.Id == 1);
```

But when doing it asynchronous:

```
var error = await SitesExpressions.View(_db.GetWorker<Vie`w>().DbSet).SingleAsync(kf => kf.Id == 1);
```

I get

> ArgumentException: Expression of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[LC.Assets.Components.Data.Models.Sites.View]'
>   cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[LC.Assets.Components.Data.Models.Sites.IView]'

I know I can change the expression to

```
IQueryable<View>
```

but I'm wondering why this happens.

**IView, View**:

```
public interface IView
{
    int SiteId { get; set; }
    string Ref { get; set; }
    Site Site { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<MetaEntry> MetaEntries { get; set; }
    string Group { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class View : IView
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<MetaEntry> MetaEntries { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this solution

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TType>> View<TType, TImplementation>(Expression<Func<TImplementation, bool>> predicate)   where TType : IView
                                                                                                                        where TImplementation : View
{
    var result = await this.DBContext.GetWorker<TImplementation>().DbSet
        .Include(vw => vw.Site)
            .ThenInclude(st => st.App)
                .ThenInclude(ap => ap.Client)
        .Include(vw => vw.Site)
            .ThenInclude(st => st.CORSEntries)
        .Include(vw => vw.Site)
            .ThenInclude(st => st.MetaEntries)
        .Where(predicate).ToListAsync();

    return (IEnumerable<TType>)result;
}
```

Invoking:

```
var test = await ex.View<IView, View>(vw => vw.Id == 1);
```